# How to apply higher order function to an effectful function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

I have too functions:

```
higherOrderPure :: (a -> b) -> c
effectful :: Monad m => (a -> m b)
```

I'd like to apply the first function to the second:

```
higherOrderPure `someOp` effectful :: Monad m => m c
```

where

```
someOp :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> c) -> (a -> m b) -> m c
```

Example:

```
curve :: (Double -> Double) -> Dia Any 
curve f = fromVertices $ map p2 [(x, f x) | x <- [1..100]]

func :: Double -> Either String Double
func _ = Left "Parse error" -- in other cases this func can be a useful arithmetic computation as a Right value

someOp :: ((Double -> Double) -> Dia Any) -> (Double -> Either String Double) -> Either String (Dia Any)
someOp = ???

curve `someOp` func :: Either String (Dia Any)
```

Comment: What is `map p2 (x, f x)` supposed to be doing?  `map p2` implies that `p2` is a function, so `(x, f x)` _must_ be a list, but it is clearly a tuple.  I also doubt that the `Dia` type is just an alias for lists, since `curve f = [...]`, meaning `curve` returns a list.  Can you update your question with a working example?  It also might help to include the type signatures of `p2` and `fromVertices`.

Comment: Sorry, typo, after p2 a [ was missing

Comment: That makes it much easier to understand what's going on, thanks!

Comment: Which library are you using to do this?  I'd like to browse its documentation to figure out if this problem is solvable in the way you want

Comment: http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/, but that's kind of irrelevant, the question is more like theoretical, the example is only for better understanding.

Comment: I still can't find a way to unify a list type with the `Diagram` type (I'm assuming you're using `type Dia a = QDiagram B R2 a` with whichever backend you're using).  Did you mean that extra layer of square brackets around `fromVerticies $ map p2 ...`?  I think instead you meant `curve f = fromVertices $ map p2 [(x, f x) | x <- [1..100]]`, since that also balances your brackets.

Comment: Indeed, there was another typo...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The type

```
Monad m => ((a -> b) -> c) -> (a -> m b) -> m c
```

is not inhabited, i.e., there is no term `t` having that type (unless you exploit divergence, e.g. infinite recursion, `error`, `undefined`, etc.).

This means, unfortunately, that it is impossible to implement the operator `someOp`.

## Proof

To prove that it is impossible to construct such a `t`, we proceed by contradiction.
Assume `t` exists with type

```
t :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> c) -> (a -> m b) -> m c
```

Now, specialize `c` to `(a -> b)`. We obtain

```
t :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)
```

Hence

```
t id :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)
```

Then, specialize the monad `m` to the continuation monad `(* -> r) -> r`

```
t id :: (a -> (b -> r) -> r) -> ((a -> b) -> r) -> r
```

Further specialize `r` to `a`

```
t id :: (a -> (b -> a) -> a) -> ((a -> b) -> a) -> a
```

So, we obtain

```
t id const :: ((a -> b) -> a) -> a
```

Finally, by the [Curry-Howard isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_isomorphism), we deduce that the following is an intuitionistic tautology:

```
((A -> B) -> A) -> A
```

But the above is the well-known [Peirce's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law), which is not provable in intuitionistic logic. Hence we obtain a contradiction.

## Conclusion

The above proves that `t` can not be implemented in a general way, i.e., working in any monad. In a specific monad this may still be possible.

Comment: `peirce k = k unsafeCoerce` :)

Comment: peirce = undefined

someOp = undefined

FunctionToSolveWorldProblems = undefined

Comment: Is it even possible to have a function of type `(a -> b) -> c`? You can have specialized versions of this type, but never this type itself, I would think: how can I write a function which, given a function between any two types you like, returns a value of any other third type you like?

Comment: @amalloy Indeed, but `Monad m => ((a -> b) -> c) -> (a -> m b) -> m c` allows for specialisation. For the argument to be uninhabited, we would have to prevent specialisation by using a higher-rank type, e.g. `(forall a. b. c. (a -> b) -> c) -> etc`.

Comment: @amalloy The polymorphic type `(a -> b) -> c` is not inhabited. If it were, the logical proposition `(A -> B) -> C` would be an intuitionistic tautology, but it is not even a classical tautology. That is, if `A=B=True` and `C=False` then `(A -> B) -> C` is false. This proves that it is not possible to construct a term of said polymorphic type. Specific instances (e.g. `a=b=c=Int`) are inhabited, though.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can achieve what you want by writing a monadic version of `curve`:

```
curveM :: Monad m => (Double -> m Double) -> m (QDiagram B R2 Any)
curveM f = do
    let xs = [1..100]
    ys <- mapM f xs
    let pts = map p2 $ zip xs ys
    return $ fromVertices pts
```

This can easily be written shorter, but it has the type you want.  This is analogous to `map -> mapM` and `zipWith -> zipWithM`.  The monadic versions of the functions have to be separated out into different implementations.

---

To test:

```
func1, func2 :: Double -> Either String Double
func1 x = if x < 1000 then Right x else Left "Too large"
func2 x = if x < 10   then Right x else Left "Too large"

> curveM func1
Right (_ :: QDiagram B R2 Any)
> curveM func2
Left "Too large"
```