# How to interact with pure algorithm in IO code

Tags: haskell, io, monads, purely-functional

To illustrate the point with a trivial example, say I have implemented `filter`:

```hs
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

And I have a predicate `p` that interacts with the real world:

```hs
p :: a -> IO Bool
```

How do it make it work with `filter` without writing a separate implementation:

```hs
filterIO :: (a -> IO Bool) -> [a] -> IO [a]
```

Presumably if I can turn `p` into `p'`:

```hs
p': IO (a -> Bool)
```

Then I can do

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  p'' <- p'
  print $ filter p'' [1..100]
```

But I haven't been able to find the conversion.

**Edited:** 
As people have pointed out in the comment, such a conversion doesn't make sense as it would break the encapsulation of the IO Monad.

Now the question is, can I structure my code so that the pure and IO versions don't completely duplicate the core logic?

Comment: It is already implemented: `filterM`.

Comment: Sure it is, but as said this is just a contrived example. Is the general solution to always implement separately a version that interacts with IO ? That'll be a lot boilerplate code for any non-trivial algorithm.

Comment: I think that would be against the use of `Monad`s. What `a -> IO Bool` means is that you feed as input a variable `a` and "it does some `IO` returning a bool". Now you want to convert that to "doing some IO returning the generic function". But in order to execute the function, one probably needs to do IO. The conversion makes - afaik - no sense at all.

Comment: Take for instance the example `FilePath -> IO String` that reads from the file and returns it content. Now you want to convert that to `IO (FilePath -> String)`? Performing IO such that you have a function that - regardless of the filename you give it - returns you its content without performing IO anymore? Mind that for instance in Linux some files are technically drivers to which you write bytes.

Comment: Make sense.  Seems like there's no choice but to have a separate function signature. But surely there are some ways to share code between the two implementation? After all the only differences between the two are lifting things in and out of IO.

Comment: indeed because a monad forces "order" so to speak, that `f` is called after `g` is called. And it can also depend on the previous call. A generic function `FilePath -> Maybe String -> IO String` could for instance act as a read/writer: if the `Maybe String` is `Just _`, the content is written to a file, so now the previous monadic call has *effects* on the next one. Because if you later decide to read from that file, the previous write will have modified something. A simple monad I sometimes use to conceptualize is the state monad: you carry a state with you and each function can read/write.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "to share code between the two implementation" do you mean to share code between `filter` and `filterM`? This sounds like either an X/Y problem (which we can't help you with without a proper example), or a hypothetical "gotcha" type question.

Comment: @jberryman: I think what the OP aims to do is "hack" the inner function out of `a -> IO b` and then use the *good old filter*.

Comment: @jberryman the original question is about whether it's possible to do without having to write a IO version of the same function(the answer seems no). The question that I asked in the comment is given pure version of the function, can you implement the IO version without re-writing everything? I have concrete example but I don't think it adds anything to the underlying question.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the impossibility of going from `a -> IO b` to `IO (a -> b)` that @WillemVanOnsem has explained reflects the difference between `Monad` and `Applicative`.

Comment: This is a potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267848/turning-a-mb-into-ma-b , especially given the last question.

Comment: @chi Given how the question has evolved, I don't think it is quite a duplicate anymore. Still, your answer there covers very well the discussion in the comments here.

Comment: @duplode Indeed, I intentionally did not vote this as a duplicate since that would close it at once. This question is more nuanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do it make it work with filter without writing a separate implementation

That isn't possible and the fact this sort of thing isn't possible is by design - Haskell places firm limits on its types and you have to obey them. You cannot sprinkle `IO` all over the place willy-nilly.

> Now the question is, can I structure my code so that the pure and IO versions don't completely duplicate the core logic?

You'll be interested in [`filterM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:filterM). Then, you can get both the functionality of `filterIO` by using the `IO` monad and the pure functionality using the [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity) monad. Of course, for the pure case, you now have to pay the extra price of wrapping/unwrapping (or `coerce`ing) the `Identity` wrapper. (Side remark: since `Identity` is a `newtype` this is only a code readability cost, not a runtime one.)

```
 ghci> data Color = Red | Green | Blue deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
```

Here is a monadic example (note that the lines containing only `Red`, `Blue`, and `Blue` are user-entered at the prompt):

```
 ghci> filterM (\x -> do y<-readLn; pure (x==y)) [Red,Green,Blue]
 Red
 Blue
 Blue
 [Red,Blue] :: IO [Color]
```

Here is a pure example:

```
 ghci> filterM (\x -> Identity (x /= Green)) [Red,Green,Blue]
 Identity [Red,Blue] :: Identity [Color]
```

Comment: Footnote: I wondered for a moment about whether there was a version of `filterM` generalised to `Applicative`; then I hoogled it and found [it is `filterM` itself](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:filterM)!

Comment: @Alec Thanks! The `Identity` monad is what I have been missing.

Comment: Minor correction: the pure example should also use `filterM`

Comment: @Chris Thanks! Important correction. - it is sort of the point of the question. :)

Comment: @duplode That bugs me so much... Only half the functions in `Control.Monad` have been generalized to `Applicative` and yet they all have the `M` suffix.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, you can use `filterM` for this specific task. However, it is usually better to keep with Haskell's characteristic strict seperation of IO and calculations. In your case, you can just tick off all necessary `IO` in one go and then do the interesting filtering in nice, reliable, easily testable pure code (i.e. here, simply with the normal `filter`):

```
type A = Int
type Annotated = (A, Bool)

p' :: Annotated -> Bool
p' = snd

main :: IO ()
main = do 
  candidates <- forM [1..100] $ \n -> do
      permitted <- p n
      return (n, permitted)
  print $ fst <$> filter p' candidates
```

Here, we first annotate each number with a flag indicating what the environment says. This flag can then simply be read out in the actual filtering step, without requiring any further IO.

In short, this would be written:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  candidates <- forM [1..100] $ \n -> (n,) <$> p n
  print $ fst <$> filter snd candidates
```

---

While it is not feasible for this specific task, I'd also add that you *can* in principle achieve the `IO` seperation with something like your `p'`. This requires that the type `A` is “small enough” that you can evaluate the predicate with *all* values that are possible at all. For instance,

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

type A = Char

p' :: IO (A -> Bool)
p' = (Map.!) . Map.fromList <$> mapM (\c -> (c,) <$> p c) ['\0'..]
```

This evaluates the predicate once for *all* of the 1114112 chars there are and stores the results in a lookup table.