# Is the a way to write a function with this signature?

Tags: haskell

I've got a function that's doing something currently working with particular datatypes. I was wondering if I could make it a general. Here's a generalised version of it's signature:

```
f :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> c -> d) -> (a -> m b) -> m c -> m d
```

If the above can't be written, perhaps the more restricted version can?

```
f2 :: Monad m => ((a -> a) -> b -> b) -> (a -> m a) -> m b -> m b
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems? Have you tried searching for those functions on Hoogle?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is impossible, at least without non-termination or unsafe operations.

The argument is essentially similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27267992/3234959): we exploit `f` to inhabit a type which we know can't be inhabited.

Assume there exists

```
f :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> c -> d) -> (a -> m b) -> m c -> m d
```

Specialize `c ~ ()`

```
f :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> () -> d) -> (a -> m b) -> m () -> m d
```

Hence

```
(\g h -> f (\x _ -> g x) h (return ()))
  :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> d) -> (a -> m b) -> m d
```

Speciazlize `d ~ a`.

```
(\g h -> f (\x _ -> g x) h (return ()))
  :: Monad m => ((a -> b) -> a) -> (a -> m b) -> m a
```

Speclialize `m ~ Cont t`

```
(\g h -> runCont $ f (\x _ -> g x) (cont . h) (return ()))
  :: ((a1 -> b) -> a) -> (a1 -> (b -> r) -> r) -> (a -> r) -> r
```

Take `h = const`

```
(\g -> runCont $ f (\x _ -> g x) (cont . const) (return ()))
  :: ((r -> b) -> a) -> (a -> r) -> r
```

Hence

```
(\g -> runCont (f (\x _ -> g x) (cont . const) (return ())) id)
  :: ((r -> b) -> r) -> r
```

So, the type `((r -> b) -> r) -> r` is inhabited, hence by the Curry-Howard isomoprhism it corresponds to a theorem of propositional intuitionistic logic. However, the formula `((A -> B) -> A) -> A` is [Peirce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce's_law) which is known to be non provable in such logic.

We obtain a contradiction, hence there is no such `f`.

---

By contrast, the type

```
f2 :: Monad m => ((a -> a) -> b -> b) -> (a -> m a) -> m b -> m b
```

is inhabited by the term

```
f2 = \ g h x -> x
```

but I suspect this is not what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem. Knowing `c` doesn't give you any information about which `a`s will be passed to `(a -> b)`. You either need to be able to enumerate the universe of `a`s or be able to inspect the provided `a` arguments with something like

```
(forall f. Functor f => ((a -> f b) -> c -> f d)
```

In which case it becomes almost trivial to implement f.

Instead of trying to implement `f` in general, you should try to generalize your functions like `((a -> b) -> c -> d)` to see if you can replace them with lenses, traversals, or something similar.