# What is a "System FC2 grammar for Kinds"?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, constraints, type-theory, type-kinds

I'm trying to wrap my head around [this blog post](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/2011/09/10/constraint-kinds-for-ghc/) about the `ConstraintKinds` extension.

There was a post in the comment section which I **totally** did not understand. Here it is:

> Adam M says: <sub>14 September 2011 19:53 UTC</sub>
>
> > Wow, this sounds great. Is it scheduled to be part of the official `GHC 7.4`?
> > Also, does this mean that you've introduced a third production in the in **System FC2 grammar for Kinds**? Currently it has `*` and `k~>k` as the only alternatives where **`k1~>k2` is (basically) the kind of `(forall a::k1 . (t::k2))`**. It sounds like this would add `k1==>k2` which is the kind of **`(a::k1 => (t::k2))`**. Or are the two kinds actually the same?

Could someone, please analyze this step-by-step or at least provide some links which would help me wrap my head around this myself. Some key moments I should pinpoint:

1. What is a "System FC2 grammar for Kinds"? (Probably the main and the most general one, whose answer would embed the two other ones.)
2. I tried explaining why "`k1~>k2` is (basically) the kind of `(forall a::k1 . (t::k2))`"? As far as I understand, `~>` is some special notation for `->` in kinds, as `*` and `k1 -> k2` the only inhabitants of the standard Haskell's kind system (fits their description: "Currently it has `*` and `k~>k` as the only alternatives"). Thus, the `(forall a::k1 . (t::k2))` formula means that if we take an inhabited type `k1`, it can be mapped onto another `k2` iff it is inhabited (due to [Curry-Howard](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/The_Curry%E2%80%93Howard_isomorphism) working for kinds the same way it works for types). Is that right? (P.S.: I see how this intuition fails if I do not understand the notion of inhabitance for kinds; do kinds correspond to <del>True</del> **provable formulae** (see comments) when they have an inhabited type as an inhabitant or an arbitrary type? The intuition fails in the second case.)
3. What does the `=>` mean in the formula for `k1==>k2`, namely `(a::k1 => (t::k2))`?

---

The response this comment got:

> Max says:
> <sub>14 September 2011 21:11 UTC</sub>
>
> > Adam: it's not that complicated! It just adds the base kind `Constraint` to the grammar of kinds. This is a kind of types inhabited by values, just like the existing kinds `*` and `#`.

So the author claims that Adam M overcomplicated the extension. Their response is quite easy to understand. Anyway, even if Adam M's comment is not true, I think it is totally worth attention as it introduced some unfamiliar concepts to me.

Comment: Personally I think Adam M is just confused. I'd ignore the comment if I were you; even setting aside whether it was more complicated than the truth or not it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, and the bits I can decipher don't seem to be correct.

Comment: @DanielWagner so the grammar for kinds does not go any further then `S to *, #, Constraint, ... | S to (S -> S)`? BTW, I offered a statement of my own in the second question. Can you comment on that one, please? Also, can you comment on the notion of inhabitance for kinds (the one I discussed in the second point as well).

Comment: The snippet you quoted in question 2 is specifically the bit I was most confident of deciphering and calling incorrect. I *still* don't recommend trying to extend it with your own thoughts. As for Curry-Howard... generally "true" is not a concept. There is provable and not provable; and though I don't know for certain, I suspect that the way most people use "inhabited" is to be as a synonym of "provable".

Comment: @DanielWagner, right, sorry, I was wrong. So, namely: Pierce's law (`((P → Q) → P) → P`) is *~generally true~* in classic logic, but it is not provable as it is a **law**. Thus, there is no function of type `∀ a b. ((a -> b) -> a) -> a` and no type operator of kind `∀ p q. ((p -> q) -> p) -> q` as they would've corresponded to the non-existing Pierce's law proof. Have I finally got that right?

Comment: That all sounds right to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner forgot to mention. I liked the trick with Pierce's law in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27267992/11143763).

Answer (score 2):

"System FC<sub>2</sub>" is a term coined by Weirich *et al* in their 2010 paper "Generative type abstraction and type-level computation" ([link](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Esweirich/newtypes.pdf)).  It refers to the addition of "roles" to *System FC* and formed the basis for the implementation in GHC described in the 2016 paper ["Safe Zero-cost Coercions for Haskell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2018/05/coercible-JFP.pdf).  *System FC*, in turn, is the system originally described in [this paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/tldi22-sulzmann-with-appendix.pdf?from=https%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fum%2Fpeople%2Fsimonpj%2Fpapers%2Fext-f%2Ftldi22-sulzmann-with-appendix.pdf) (or actually an earlier paper of which this is post-publication extended version), which extended the usual polymorphic lambda calculus of *System F* with type equalities.

**However**, I think Adam M was probably using the term "System FC<sub>2</sub>" less formally to refer to whatever type system GHC was implementing at the time the comment was written.  So, the meaning of the phrase:

> introduced a third production in the System FC2 grammar for Kinds

is really:

> added a third production rule to the grammar of kinds, as kinds are currently implemented in GHC

His claim was that the grammar for kinds currently had two production rules:

1. `*` is a kind
2. If `k1` and `k2` are kinds, then `k1 ~> k2` is a kind.

and he was asking if this extension gave a third production rule:

3. If `k1` and `k2` are kinds, then `k1 ==> k2` is a kind.

As you've guessed, he introduced the operator `~>` to differentiate the kind-level arrow from the type-level arrow.  (In GHC, both the kind-level and type-level arrow operators are written the same way `->`.)  He gave a definition of `~>` as:

> where `k1~>k2` is (basically) the kind of `(forall a::k1 . (t::k2))`.

which is interpretable, but very imprecise.  He was trying to use `forall` here as a sort of type-level lambda.  It's not, but you can imagine that if you had a type `forall a. t`, you could instantiate it at a specific type `a`, and if for all `a :: k1` you get `t :: k2`, then this polymorphic type sort of represents an implicit type function of kind `k1 ~> k2`.  But the polymorphism / universal quantification is irrelevant here.  What's important is how `a` appears in the expression `t`, and the extent to which you can express the type-level expression `t` as, say, a type-level function:

```
type Whatever a = t
```

or if Haskell had type-level lambdas, a type-level lambda with `a` as an argument and `t` as its body:

```
Lambda a. t
```

You won't get anywhere by trying to seriously consider `forall a. t` as having kind `k1 -> k2`.

Based on this loose interpretation of `~>`, he tried to ask if there was a new, kind-level operator `==>` such that the relationship between the kind-level operator `~>` and the type-level expression `forall a. b` was the same as the relationship between a new hypothetical kind-level operator `==>` and the type-level expression `a => b`.  I think the only reasonable way to interpret this question is to imagine that he wanted to consider the type expression `a => b` as being parameterized by `a`, the same way he was imagining `forall a. b` as being parameterized by `a`, so he wanted to consider a type-level function of the form:

```
type Something a = a => b
```

and consider the kind of `Something`.  Here, the kind of `Something` is `Constraint ~> *`.   So, I guess the answer to his final question is, "the two kinds are actually the same", and no other kind-level operator besides `~>` is needed.

Max's reply explained that the extension didn't add any new kind-level operator but merely added a new primitive kind, `Constraint` at the same grammatical level as the kinds `*` and `#`.  The kind-level `~>` operator has the same relationship to type-level application `f a` whether the primitive kinds involved are `*` or `#` or `Constratin`.  So, for example, given:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, RankNTypes #-}
type Whatever a = Maybe [a]
type Something a = a => Int
```

the kinds of `Whatever` and `Something` are both expressed in terms of the kind operator `~>` (in GHC, written simply `->`):

```
λ> :kind Whatever
Whatever :: * -> *
λ> :kind Something
Something :: Constraint -> *
```