# Is there a way to commute monads automatically?

Tags: haskell, monads, lift

I have written a program to pull a `Maybe` out of a pair:

```
deMaybe :: (a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a, b)
deMaybe (_, Nothing) = Nothing
deMaybe (x,Just y) = Just (x, y)
```

I know that `Maybe` is a monad and `(,) a` is a functor (among other typeclasses). I'm wondering if there is a higher-level function I'm missing, such as:

```
commute :: (Functor f, Monad m) => f (m a) -> m (f a)
```

My question is: can I write `deMaybe` with a more general type signature like that of the hypothetical `commute`, acknowledging that I am trying to commute one functor past another? Can this be done using functions such as `fmap`, `>>=`, `pure`, &c.?

Comment: You can work with `sequence`

Comment: In the general case, commutation is impossible: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267848/turning-a-mb-into-ma-b) focuses on the differences between `m (a->b)` and `a->m b`. Even if `(a->)` is a functor, and `m` is a monad, these do not commute in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can work with [**`sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence), but this requires a `Traversable`. For `t ~ (b, )` and `m ~ Maybe`, this thus works as:

```
Prelude> sequence (2, Just 3)
Just (2,3)
Prelude> sequence (2, Nothing)
Nothing
```

A `Traversable` is a typeclass for data structures that can be transformed to an item with the same shape. We need this to construct thus a 2-tuple (or list, or something similar).

or we can use [**`sequenceA :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => t (f a) -> f (t a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequenceA) as [@chepner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049834/is-there-a-way-to-commute-monads-automatically/72049872?noredirect=1#comment127309225_72049872), which is more general since all `Monad`s are also `Applicative`s:

```
Prelude> sequenceA (2, Just 3)
Just (2,3)
Prelude> sequenceA (2, Nothing)
Nothing
```

Comment: There's also `sequenceA`, as we only need `Maybe` to be an applicative functor, not necessarily a monad.