# Is there any typeclass that defines the function from `a -> m b` to `m (a -> b)`?

Tags: haskell, distributive

The function from `a -> m b` to `m (a -> b)` rarely appears in programming, but can be made in the Reader monad. The following code is a tentative implementation. Does such a library exist?

```hs
class Monad m => MonadShift m where
  shift :: (a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)

instance MonadShift Identity where
  shift f = Identity (\x -> runIdentity (f x))

instance MonadShift m => MonadShift (ReaderT r m) where
  shift f = ReaderT (\r -> shift (\x -> runReaderT (f x) r))
```

Comment: You might also want to read [Turning `A -> M B` into `M (A -> B)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267848/turning-a-mb-into-ma-b) which explains that there is no way to implement that for general monads, so we really need to use a typeclass for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a specialization of [`distribute :: Functor f => f (g a) -> g (f a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:distribute) of the [`Distributive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html#t:Distributive) class where `f` is the Functor `(->) b`. Then you get the type signature:

```
distribute :: (b -> g a) -> g (b -> a)
```

Note that (1) this doesn't require `g` to be a `Monad`, but just a `Functor`, and (2) the `Identity` and `ReaderT` instances are basically the only instances that you can define:

> Categorically every Distributive functor is actually a right adjoint, and so it must be Representable endofunctor and preserve all limits. This is a fancy way of saying it is isomorphic to (->) x for some x.

Comment: On note (1), it's worth mentioning that all distributive functors are monads, even though the `Data.Distributive` formulation doesn't express that for technical reasons. That being so, asking `Distributive` is stronger than asking just for `Monad`.

Answer (score 5):

This question provides a nice opportunity to collect information about this function that is scattered across multiple Q&As around here. Since it doesn't really have a standard name, I will just call it `shift` like you did.

[As Noughtmare points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75928695/2751851), one way in which `shift` arises is as a specialisation of [`distribute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:distribute):

```
distribute :: (Distributive g, Functor f) => f (g a) -> g (f a)

shift :: Distributive g => (r -> g a) -> g (r -> a)
shift = distribute @_ @((->) _)
```

If we instead specialise `g`, the other functor in the type of `distribute`, to a function functor, we get a combinator variously known as [`flap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-1.2.0.0/docs/Relude-Functor-Fmap.html#v:flap) or [`(??)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.2.2/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-63--63-):

```
flap :: Functor f => f (s -> a) -> (s -> f a)
flap = distribute @((->) _)
-- flap m s = (\f -> f s) <$> m
```

(If we do both specialisations at once, we end up with `flip` from the Prelude.)

Since `distribute . distribute = id`, `shift` and `flap` are full inverses:

```
flap . shift = id
shift . flap = id
```

Given a distributive functor `g`, `shift` and `flap` therefore give us an isomorphism between Kleisli arrows `a -> g b` and static arrows `g (a -> b)`. That reflects how the monad and applicative instances of a distributive functor are ultimately equivalent. Such a fact is [more readily verified for the function functor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136614/2751851), and extends to the other distributives through the `Representable` isomorphism alluded to by Noughtmare's answer. (By the way, all distributive functors are indeed monads, even though that is not obvious from looking at `Data.Distributive` given how the API of said module is currently laid out.)

Lastly, while `shift` is a specialisation of `distribute`, it is possible to turn things around and express `distribute` in terms of `shift`:

```
distribute m = (\p -> p <$> m) <$> shift id
```

We can think of `shift id :: Distributive g => g (g a -> a)` as holding at each position of the distributive functor shape a `g a -> a` extractor for that position, which is bound to `p` in the definition above. That being so, mapping over `shift id` makes it possible to pick values from matching positions within `m :: f (g a)`.