# Haskell: Is it possible to write a function with signature Monad m => (a -> m a) -> m (a -> a)

Tags: haskell, monads

Is it possible to write a function with signature `Monad m => (a -> m a) -> m (a -> a)` ?

For example I have a function

```hs
func :: Int -> IO Int
func n = pure $ n + 1
```

Can I transform it into `func' :: IO (Int -> Int)` ?

Comment: well imagine that `m ~ []` (`[]` is an instance of `Monad`), then you thus convert an `Int -> [Int]` for example to an `[Int -> Int]`. Not in general no.

Comment: For certain monadic instances that is possible, I unfortunately can not remember instantly the name of this algebraic structure, but not for monads in general.

Comment: For `IO` it also makes no sense, an `IO` action that returns a function is something else than a function that retuns an `IO` action.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The structure is `Distributive` (or, equivalently, `Representable`). See also: [*Is there any typeclass that defines the function from a -> m b to m (a -> b)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75928651/2751851)

Comment: "Is it possible to write a function with signature `Monad m => (a -> m a) -> m (a -> a)` ?" If you just care about that type, then `const (pure id)` will do, but I imagine that doesn't work the way you had in mind.

Comment: Also, consider what would happen if you transformed `readFile` the way you had in mind.